# expect fail when testing css class with 'toHaveStyle'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I created a demo using react+materialUI and I'm using the Table Component with a custom theme applied.
I'm testing if the correct color (the one from my theme) is appplied, but the 'toHaveStyle' is getting the first class applied (the default from MaterialUI), not the one my theme overrides. The output:

Expected

-- color: rgb(3, 64, 187);

++ color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);

Here's the demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-wozniak-c62l0

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is great that you have included a codesandbox, but please also include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you are applying your theme colour correctly. Your class `header` is override the main colour from TableCell component. Do you want all table content colour with the primary one?